# Django 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: ajax, django, http-status-code-403

When I try the ajax in same page to html it works. Like this;

```
<html>
    <head>
     ...
    </head>
    <body>
     ....
     <script>

    $.ajax({
        url: /test/,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        data: { name: a, surname: b},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            getList(data);
        }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try the call same javascript as external. It doesn't work. Why?

```
<html>
    <head>
     ...
    </head>
    <body>
     ....
     <script src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you configure static file properly in django?

Comment: static file properly configured. I have 403 error.

Comment: [The docs have a solution for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) that automatically adds the CSRF token to all AJAX calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the `{{ csrf_token }}` as a global variable in your HTML page in `script` tag as a global variable as such:-

```
var generated_csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
```

And then in your .js file call it,

```
headers: {'X-CSRFToken': generated_csrf_token},
```

But make sure you put AJAX call within the document ready func in `$(document).ready(function () {***here***}`

This way you can access it with name `generated_csrf_token` in any js file.

Hope this helps :-)