# Django 1.11: Dynamic Javascript to load Google Map markers

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to dynamically insert markers data (name, latitude, long) into javascript, `maps.js`.

In my maps.js, I currently have:

```
var locations = [
        [ locationData('listings1.html','images/listing-item-01.jpg',"listing name",'Address ', '4.5', '12'), 40.94401669296697, -74.16938781738281, 1, '<i class="im im-icon"></i>'],
        [ locationData('listings2.html','images/listing-item-02.jpg','Name2','Place', '5.0', '23'), 40.77055783505125, -74.26002502441406,          2, '<i class="im im-icon"></i>'],];
```

And I need to be able to load this dynamically using a for loop e.g.

```
{% if listings %}
var locations = [
{% for listing in listings %}
[ locationData({{ listing.url}} , {{ listing.name }} , {{ listing.place }}) ],
{% endfor %}
]
```

Currently I have a maps.js static file, which I load using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts/maps.js' %}"></script>
```

I can't insert the tags there, because it's called statically. 
However, since `maps.js` is `static`, I can't load tags such as `{{ listing.location }} , {{ listing.lat }} , {{ listing.lng }}` etc.

I tried 2 solutions (and the one described in the comments).

1) I tried loading the a small

```
#template.html
<script>
var locations = 
// python code
</script>
```

but this didn't work, I think because `locationData` is a function, which is also defined in maps.js.

I could possibly include the whole of `maps.js` in `template.html`, but it's 230 lines of code.

2) I tried adding `maps.js` to my `users` app folder, as so:

```
users/templates/users/maps.js
```

And inside that js I loaded template tags defined above. In my views.py I did:

```
def index(request):
    js_file = "users/templates/users/maps.js" 

    return render(request, "users/template.html", context={"js_file": js_file })

#template.html

<script src="{{js_file}}"></script>
```

However, I get the error that the file couldn't be found.

Answer (score 2):

Load your static file in the same manner:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts/maps.js' %}"></script>
```

For passing values such as `{{ model.location }} , {{ model.lat }} , {{ model.lng }}` to your js file, save them as global variable in `script` tag in your HTML page as,

```
var location = "{{ model.location }}";
var lat = "{{ model.lat }}";
var lng = "{{ model.lng }}";
```

And refer them in `maps.js` by `location` `lat` and `lng`.

Further on to pass an array of data you can do it somewhat like this,

```
 var locationsArray = [
                {% for location in locations %}

                    {
                        id: {{ location.pk }}, name: '{{ location.name|escapejs }}',
                        lat: '{{ location.lat }}',
                        lng: "{{ location.lng }}"
                    },

                {% endfor %}
            ];
```

Hope this Helps :-)

Comment: I tried doing this, in the template I defined the var locations, and simply copy pasted the code from maps.js to define the variable outside maps.js. Then I commented out the maps.js var locations, but this doesn't work

Comment: This solution should work i have solved my such issues in this manner only. Check out my this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46302661/4834455 you might get some more clues from this.

Comment: Having done this, I can see how this would work for just 1 entry. But how would you incorporate a loop into this? I need the maps.js file to have as many locations (markers) as the number of entries my model returns

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592811/returning-json-array-from-a-django-view-to-a-template) could help you. when you put in context some structure and then render it in template with "safe" filter